# Can I use useReducer from outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Now I'm trying to use useReducer to created a new way for management state and function but now found the problem is "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"
Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
// App Component
import React from "react";

import { product, productDis } from "./ProductReducer";
//{product} is state,  {productDis} is dispatch

import { total } from "./TotalReducer";
//{total} is state and i dont need {totalDis}


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>productDis({type:'add',payload:'pen'})}>add</button>
      {product} {total}
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

```
// ProductReducer Component
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import {totalDis} from './TotalReducer'
//{totalDis} is dispatch and i dont need {total}


export const [product, productDis] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "add": {
            const product_0 = 'pencil'
            const product_1 = `${action.payload} and ${product_0}`
            totalDis({
                type:'total_add',
                payload:'250'
            })
            return product_1;
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}, []);
```

```
// TotalReducer Component
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export const [total, totalDis] = useReducer((total, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "total_add": {
            const vat = action.payload*1.15
            return vat;
        }
        default:
            return total;
    }
}, 0)
```

when i click the button on display It should be shown..." pen and pencil 287.5 "

but it show "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

there any way to solve this problem? or i should back to nature?

Comment: You can't use `useReducer` outside of a function component, but you can put the [reducer function and initial state outside of it if you prefer, like the example in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

Comment: thanks but i if I create a new component such as Order component and in the new component i want to access ProductReducer without useContext I can import ProductReducer and it can return state for my new component too

Comment: No, you can't do this the way you want.

Answer (score 14):

React hooks should be called only inside functional components. Hook state is maintained per component instance. If hooks have to be reused, they can be extracted into custom hooks, which are functions that call built-in hooks and are supposed to be called inside functional components:

```
export const useTotal = () => {
  const [total, totalDis] = useReducer((total, action) => {...}, 0);
  ...
  return [total, totalDis];
};
```

In case there's a need to maintain common state for multiple components it should be maintained in common parent and be provided to children through props:

```
const Root = () => (
  const [total, totalDispatcher] = useTotal();

  return <App {...{total, totalDispatcher}}/>
);

const App = props => {
  return (
    <div>{props.total}</div>
  );
};
```

Or context API:

```
const TotalContext = createContext();

const Root = () => (
  <TotalContext.Provider value={useTotal()}>
    <App/>
  </TotalContext.Provider>
);

const App = () => {
  const [total] = useContext(TotalContext);
  return (
    <div>{total}</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.

Comment: @BryanGrace Can't say about any question, but it definitely answers the question above - whether useReducer can be used inside the component and what are the workarounds. If you didn't understand something, you could ask for a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

With `useEnhancedReducer` hook introduced [here](https://transang.me/get-state-callback-with-usereducer/) which returns `getState` function.

You will have something like.

```
const [state, dispatch, getState] = useEnahancedReducer(reducer, initState)
```

Because `dispatch`, `getState` will never change, they can be used in some hooks without their appearance in the dependence list, they can be stored somewhere else (outside of react) to to be called at anytime, from anywhere.

There is also version of `useEnhancedReducer` which supports adding middleware, in the same article.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html),

There are three common reasons you might be seeing it:

- You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.
- You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
- You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

Deep drive to the docs. I hope, you'll be able to resolve the issue. Especially see:

## Breaking the Rules of Hooks:

```
function Counter() {
  // ✅ Good: top-level in a function component
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  // ...
}

function useWindowWidth() {
  // ✅ Good: top-level in a custom Hook
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  // ...
}
```

If you break these rules, you might see this error.

```
function Bad1() {
  function handleClick() {
    //  Bad: inside an event handler (to fix, move it outside!)
    const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  }
  // ...
}

function Bad2() {
  const style = useMemo(() => {
    //  Bad: inside useMemo (to fix, move it outside!)
    const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
    return createStyle(theme);
  });
  // ...
}

class Bad3 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    //  Bad: inside a class component
    useEffect(() => {})
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

To conclude, your error seems to be appearing as if you're using reducer inside click handler. Check the example **Bad1** to resolve your issue. What I mean here is you shouldn't be doing like this:

```
onClick={()=>productDis({type:'add',payload:'pen'})}
```

In the onClick handler, dispatch the action and inside a method use that reducer.

Comment: I like how React devs decided that you shouldn't be doing like this and you should do like that. Makes no sense why both ways didn't work.

Comment: @ArtemP it's all about them side effects.